# Removable drive not showing up in MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, android

I am using Phone One Plus 6T and connect it to my MacBook to transfer files.

Everytime I connected it to my MacBook, I selected the option "File transfer" and it all used to work fine with a USB drive showing up in Finder.

But now its not working and the only change which I know of is that I upgraded to Catalina.

I have checked System Information and the USB drive is getting detected. In Finder preferences, the option  "Show External Drives" is selected.

Can someone please guide on how to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS Catalina that's currently running on your Mac?

Comment: Catalina version is 10.15.3

Comment: Wouldn't you need the File Transfer App for Android to do that?

Comment: Have you tried with another USB cable ? You can also try to go in Settings > Developer Options > Check USB Debugging and choose "Media device (MTP)” option.

Comment: @Lulucmy Yes i have tried that option.